# Set environment variable using command line arguments

Tags: parameters, aurelia

Is it possible to pass values for environment variables using command line arguments?

E.g. I'd like to set a version number which is generated by my build server:

**aurelia_project/environments/prod.ts**

```js
export default {
    debug: false,
    testing: false,
    // $buildVersion$ should be replaced during build with the actual value
    buildVersion: $buildVersion$
};
```

Imaginary command: `au build --env prod --buildVersion 1.1.1`

---

**Edit**
Since it doesn't seem to be possible right now, I've created a feature request on Aurelias [GitHub pages](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/522)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [proposed by AStoker](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/522#issuecomment-286187932) I was able to solve this the following way:

**aurelia_project/environments/prod.ts**

```js
export default {
    debug: false,
    testing: false,
    buildVersion: {buildVersion} // <-- Will be replace during build
};
```

**aurelia_project/transpile.js**

```js
// ...
import * as replace from 'gulp-replace';

function configureEnvironment() {
    let env = CLIOptions.getEnvironment();
    let buildVersion = CLIOptions.getFlagValue('buildVersion') || '0.0.0';

    return gulp.src(`aurelia_project/environments/${env}.ts`)
        .pipe(changedInPlace({firstPass: true}))
        .pipe(replace('{buildVersion}', buildVersion)) // <-- Replacement happens here
        .pipe(rename('environment.ts'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(project.paths.root));
}
// ...
```

Command line call: `au build --buildVersion 1.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible. This could be an enhancement down the road. I'd recommend filing an enhancement request here: https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/new